# Find values of $x$ so that $f_n(x)=\frac {nx^{n-1}} {1+x^{2n}}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

I noticed that $\int f_n(x)dx=\text{arctan}(x^n)$ but I don't know how to continue

Comment: Do we want $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)$ to exist or $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$ to converge? Also worth noting: $f_n(1/x) = x^2 f_n(x)$.

Comment: Consider $|x|<1$, $|x|>1$ and $|x|=1$. Does this help?